# Using php namespaces properly

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to figure out how to use the namespace in php. I have been reading about how to use it and for some reason I can not get it to work. I have two files one which I have stored in `Applications/Database/Classes` file name is `DatabaseConnection.php` and the other in the root directory called `DB.php`inside the `DatabaseConnection.php` file I have the following code:

```
<?php
    function hello()
    {
        echo "hello";
    }
?>
```

This is the DB.php file contents:

```
<?php
namespace Applications\Database\Classes;
ini_set('display_errors', true);
hello();
?>
```

Maybe I am completely missing how to use it properly but if I set a namespace is that the same as using `include` or `require`? I might be completely misunderstanding how to use it. I am new to OOP and have never heard of namespaces until I started trying to learn OOP? Can someone point out what I did wrong.

Comment: I know some Trekkies ... they use spacenames nearly in the same way you do ;)

Comment: I never got into star trek

Comment: namespaces dont automatically require files. You could however use an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: @Yamaha32088 You did not get it!

Comment: I know I didn't get it haha

Comment: [This image](http://1-media-cdn.foolz.us/ffuuka/board/q/image/1366/90/1366906518725.png) applies well here I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces are for organizing your code in so that you can divide components up and help with the readability. For example if I have a class `Pittbull` and another `Dashund` I can place them into a namespace like so for organization:

```
Animals.Dogs.Pittbull
Animals.Dogs.Dashund
```

This also helps with potential collisions like the below:

```
Animals.Dogs.Misc
Animals.Cats.Misc
```

The `Misc` class exists twice in this instance, but instead of there being a conflict of which `Misc` to use, you can use the same class name for both classes (and have different properties and methods inside of them) and not have a conflict of which one you want to use.

The `require` keyword is a completely different concept and is used to load actual files into the executing script.

Answer (score 0):

Instruction how to use autoloading in PHP (PSR-0):
https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md